# File does not exist: favicon.ico

Tags: perl, apache, apache2

I can run my perl file perfectly two weeks ago, but today I rerun it, the error_log file shows me this:

```
[Sat Nov 17 19:33:04 2012] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/xxx/xxx/apache2/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Sat Nov 17 19:33:05 2012] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/xxx/xxx/apache2/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Sat Nov 17 19:33:06 2012] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/xxx/xxx/apache2/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Sat Nov 17 19:33:06 2012] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/xxx/xxx/apache2/htdocs/favicon.ico
.
.
.
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked to see if the file is there?
is it readable by apache?

can you change the path to a http://domain.com/favicon.ico and test it and see if it works?

Comment: No, there isn't such a file in htdocs, and I dont think I've seen it before.

Comment: this file is commonly referenced by internet browsers such as firefox, internet explorer to display a picture in the address bar. I believe this file is also used when you bookmark the page and also save it to your desktop as a hyperlink.

this error can be ignored as it won't stop the general functions of your website.

Comment: what is your perl code trying to perform? why is it relying on this error log file to be null?
you can void this error simply by creating a fake favicon.ico file and the error should disappear.

Comment: It is better for favicon.ico to be an empty file rather than not exist. When its an empty file, apache does not have to write to the error log on every request.

Answer (score 1):

I  assume this is a CGI script or something similar. favicon.ico is the icon shown in the urlbar of browsers when visiting the site. It will be requested, but if no found is simply not displayed since favicon.ico are optional. The error is indicating that the browser is trying to get the favicon and not finding it, not a problem as such, if you weren't getting it before it could just mean you were accessing from a different browser.

Of course if this is not a CGI script you're accessing through a browser then this doesn't apply and you really need to provide a code snippet.

Comment: I tried both Firefox and Chrome, it shows the same thing. DO you know how to provide the code snippet?